# AsyncTask onPreExecute new progressdialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
class AddStudent extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ResultData> {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AddStudentActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Adding Product..");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
}

private Context context;
  //CHANGE HERE....ADD PARAMATER

TextView tv_msg;
public AddStudent(Context context, TextView tv_msg) {
    this.context = context;
    this.tv_msg = tv_msg;

}
```

I have an error in `(AddStudentActivity.this);`

> Error = com.blablablabla.AddStudentActivity is not an enclosing class.

What's the problem?.
 
How can I fix this?.

Comment: You cannot use the context of an Activity which hasn't been created yet..

Answer (score 2):

If the asynctask is not a nested class of an activity you need to set/add the context as a parameter to the constructor.

```
 class AddStudent extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ResultData> {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private Context context;

    public AddStudent(Context context) {
       this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context) ;
        pDialog.setMessage("Adding Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
}
```

TextView it is part of the activity. 
   Or, if the asynctask is a nested class of an activity, then you can do what you want. More you can read in the example below:

[ProgressDialog and AsyncTask](http://android-er.blogspot.co.at/2015/02/progressdialog-and-asynctask.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have not posted your entire code, so this is a bit of speculation, but here goes:

Most probably you have created a separate file for your `AddStudent` AsyncTask, or put it outside your `AddStudentActivity` class. You need to make `AddStudent` an inner class of `AddStudentActivity` to be able to use `AddStudentActivity.this`.

More info here : [Android: AsyncTask recommendations: private class or public class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823891/android-asynctask-recommendations-private-class-or-public-class)

Answer (score 1):

pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AddStudentActivity.this) ;

change to

pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context) ;

its work.

Answer (score 0):

**Error = com.blablablabla.AddStudentActivity is not an enclosing class.**

above error comes whenever you try to use Activity context in other separate class . 
This should even harmful for you when it will give you memory leaks.

pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);